# Java 8 stream filter on multiple filters

Tags: filter, java-8, java-stream, autowired

I have a list of filters and I want to apply them on a stream of Order:

```
@Autowired
private List<Filter> filters;
```

Where Filter is an interface:

```
public interface Filter {

boolean filter(Order order);}
```

I found that I can do something like

```
 orders
.stream()
.filter(order -> filter1.filter(order))
.filter(order -> filter2.filter(order))...
```

But such approach is not correct as my list is dynamic. Can someone help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to create a `Predicate` out of all your filters. For this, you can reduce them to a final `Predicate` by means of the AND operator:

```
Predicate<Order> predicate = filters.stream()
    .map(f -> (Predicate<Order>) f::filter)
    .reduce(Predicate::and)
    .orElse(o -> true);
```

Now, you can apply this predicate to the stream of orders:

```
orders.stream()
    .filter(predicate)
    ...
```